# How to import project lib to Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I tried to import [MaskedEditText](https://github.com/toshikurauchi/MaskedEditText) to my project, but the results are not good.

What I did for importing the library:

1. Download from github.
2. File -> New -> Import module -> Choose project -> Next.
   [image]
3. Use it:

   ```
   <br.com.sapereaude.maskedEditText.MaskedEditText
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       mask:mask="###.###.###-##"
       />
   ```

I get this error:

```
Error:(13) No resource identifier found for attribute 'mask' in package 'com.bottom.smart.masktekst'
Error:(17, 20) Color value not valid -- must be #rgb, #argb, #rrggbb, or #aarrggbb (at 'mask' with value '###.###.###-##').
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'D:\work\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702\sdk\build-tools\build-tools-22.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Set your tree view in Android Studio as **Project**. Then find folder **libs** - (Your project folder > app > libs )
2. Drag & drop `*.jar` file to this folder.
3. File > Project Structure > Module: app > Dependencies tab
4. Click add button, File Dependency. Expand libs folder and choose your `*.jar`. Save changes.
5. Let your gradle sync.

**Edit:**

I decided to compile it by myself. Change your parent layout from `xmlns:xmask="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` to `xmlns:mask="http://schemas.android.com/tools"`.

Comment: Thanks for unswer. I download jar from [here](https://github.com/toshikurauchi/MaskedEditText/blob/master/MaskedEditText/bin/maskededittext.jar) then i add its jar to [my project](http://take.ms/qPD1d) but i dont now why i have still same error(

Comment: The schema should stay as `res-auto`. Not that it won't work this way, but that is the accepted convention. The only thing that needed changing was `xlmns:xmask` to `xlmns:mask` (or changing `mask:mask` to `xmask:mask` in the `MaskedEditText` entry would also be fine).

Comment: i do everything what you say, but i dont know why i have still same error this is [my settings](http://take.ms/vfHAR) `Error:(12) No resource identifier found for attribute 'mask' in package 'com.bottom.smart.masktekst'` My project cant find this lib

Comment: I made a rollback on my answer (`tools`), try now.

Comment: I try it, but [have error](http://take.ms/I0TCj) `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class br.com.sapereaude.maskedEditText.MaskedEditText`  I do not know why it does not work, honestly I have tried a lot of things

Comment: File -> Invalidate cache / restart -> Invalidate cache / restart

Comment: @DamianKozlak I did what you said, but i have still this error: `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class br.com.sapereaude.maskedEditText.MaskedEditText`

Comment: Can you share this project with me? Place on GitHub, GitLab or just packed at ZippyShare? I have no clue what's wrong.

Comment: I have checked it. It's not your problem. It's the problem with the library caused by author. He didn't include properly `styleable` to library. I can do nothing with it. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I include this libruary this:

**1.** Create folder in project, its name "**libraries**", then add this folder "**MaskedEditText**" folder

[image]

**2.** Include it in settings.gradle

`include ':libraries:MaskedEditText'`

**3.** In folder "**MaskedEditText**" create file **build.gradle**

[image]

and add this code:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'
    }
}


apply plugin: 'android-library'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 22
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

    }
}
```

**4.** In app/build.grdle add this:

```
compile project(':libraries:MaskedEditText')
```

And its work =)